# How to run the java code from command prompt which is dependent on many other projects

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven. I have maven code repository synced in eclipse. I have a one main file say `Main.java` which is dependent on several other projects which I have added using maven. I am able to run `Main.java` from eclipse.

How can I run the same file from command prompt?

Comment: You will have to add all the sources to classpath to run the Main.java file. Better package the project as a runnable jar and then run the jar from command prompt using 'java -jar <jar-file>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the class you are trying to run has a main method, try the command `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=yourpackage.yourClassName`

Comment: You can find additional information about the Exec plugin on [this page](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)